# How to omit the last four lines of a sample code in listing

Tags: listings, xml

I am using the listings package to include xml samples in the documentation I am writing.

I am aware of the firstline and lastline attributes

```
\lstinputlisting[firstline=4,lastline=24]{example.xml}
```

The size of the XML files will change overtime. In stead of having to change the lastline argument of each listing, I would like to state that the last x lines should be omitted for inclusion, is this at all possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\sbox0{\lstinputlisting{example.xml}}
\lstinputlisting[firstline=4,lastline=\the\numexpr\value{lstnumber}-5\relax]{example.xml}
```

This save your input file in a box to count its lines number (so the file is not typeset in the document). This number is saved in the `lstnumber` counter so you can then use it to set your last line when you really insert the code. If you want to not show the last 4 lines you have subtract 5 to the counter because it is incremented after the end of a line. So if your file has 8 lines after the first call of `\lstinputlisting` the counter is set to 9.

This can be adapted to allow you to write

```
\lstinputlisting[firstline=4,lastline=-4]{example.xml}
```

for omitting the last four lines, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\lst@Key{lastline}\relax{\ifnumcomp{#1}{<}{0}{%
  \let\mylst@file\lst@intname\sbox0{\lstinputlisting{\mylst@file}}%
  \def\lst@lastline{\the\numexpr#1+\value{lstnumber}-1\relax}}%
  {\def\lst@lastline{#1\relax}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[firstline=4,lastline=-4]{example.xml}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does one do if one does not want to include a full listing at any point in the file?

Comment: @AndrewSwann my edits answer to your question?

Comment: Indeed.  I have taken the liberty of updating your answer with how to include this as a key.