# How to omit the last n lines from an inline listing?

Tags: listings

This is a followup to [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134854/how-to-omit-the-last-four-lines-of-a-sample-code-in-listing) addressing the corresponding issue with listings from external files.

The ideal solution would be extending the `lastline` key to accept negative values and count omitted lines from the end, just like [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134860/82186) to the linked question.

The main reason for desiring a redefinition of `lastline` instead of some new environment (that might be easier to implement) is the ease of integration with other packages, e.g. `tcolorbox`.

A non-working minimal example would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[lastline=-2]
first
second
third
fourth
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

where only the first and second line of the listing would be in the output.

The core trick of the linked answer consists of setting the listing a first time in a box, getting the value of the line counter (still holding the index of the last line) and setting the listing a second time calculating the correct value for `lastline`. I tried adapting it to this situation without success, as I don't know the innards of `listings` well enough. Can it be done?

Comment: Would you like to export the content to an external file and apply the existing solution?

Comment: Not what I had in mind, but I guess it'd be an acceptable solution! Apart from not breaking any feature of `listings`, I only care about having a seamless integration into the `lastline` key so it can be effortlessly used coupled with other packages like `showexpl`and `tcolorbox`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you intend to use this feature for `tcolorbox`, as you wrote, there is an easy way. The `tcblistings` environment saves the listings content into a file and reloads it again. Therefore, the patch from [How to omit the last four lines of a sample code in listing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134854/how-to-omit-the-last-four-lines-of-a-sample-code-in-listing/134860#134860) can be applied:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\lst@Key{lastline}\relax{\ifnumcomp{#1}{<}{0}{%
  %\let\mylst@file\lst@intname\sbox0{\lstinputlisting{\mylst@file}}% UPDATE
  \sbox0{\lstinputlisting{\kvtcb@listingfile}}% UPDATE
  \def\lst@lastline{\the\numexpr#1+\value{lstnumber}-1\relax}}%
  {\def\lst@lastline{#1\relax}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{listing options={lastline=-2}}
first
second
third
fourth
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing only,listing options={lastline=-2}}
first
second
third
fourth
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{blankest,listing only,listing options={lastline=-2}}
first
second
third
fourth
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since nobody chimed in with a completely general solution I'll accept the answer, as it perfectly fits my use case. (Thanks for the awesome `tcolorbox` package!)

Comment: Something inside `listings` changed (I didn't track down what exactly) and `\lst@intname` is not working anymore in this case. A fix I found is using `tcolorbox`'s `\kvtcb@listingfile` internal instead. Would that be sound @thomas-f-sturm?

Comment: @PaoloBrasolin I also do not know what was changed inside `listings`, but you are right that `\kvtcb@listingfile` can be used as replacement. I updated my answer with a replaced code line.